# When to obtain the right frame size

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, frame

The problem: Let's suppose I have an image and an element which constantly triggers viewDidLayoutSubviews (a scrollview.. so that at every scroll viewDidLayout would be called... or whatever element that triggers viewDidLayout quite often).

This image as well as the "viewDidLayout_element" are all set up well with autolayout in the storyboard.

Now:
I need to make the image to be a rounded one. 
with the typical: layer.cornerRadius.. and layer.masksToBounds. This requires a calculated imageView frame.

In what view controller cycle do I make it programatically? Taking into consideration that:

*except for the viewDidLayoutSubviews I don't get the right frame

*the viewDidLayoutSubviews can be called even thousands of times depending on the "viewDidLayout_element" that triggers it.

*If I call layoutIfNeeded on the imageView in viewDidAppear (because it's the only case when frames are already available so we can force their calculation) the user will already catch a glimpse of the transformation from a square image to a circular image. In other words in viewDidAppear the frame becomes available for our manipulation, but is also available for milliseconds to the user's eyes.

*it does not make sense to fill the viewDidLayoutSubviews with flags (especially if there will be something more performance intensive than a circular imageView transformation) like below:

```
if !iDidChangedTheImage
{
    imageView.applyCornerRadius()
}
```

The question:

Where do I have the correct frame size inside a viewController cycle without the problems from above? Or how do you usually solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `UIImageView` to your custom class, and override `layoutSubviews`. After that you don't need to care about image view size change and updating corner radius, just use that class for your custom image view

```
@implementation CustomImageView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2.0;
}

@end
```